# Next.JS - TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql-js

I'm using the qraphql-request library to fetch data.
The request to the data is stored in a directory called video/[slug].js

here's the code for the data fetching:

```
import {gql, GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'

export const getServerSideProps = async (pageContext) => {
   const url = process.env.ENDPOINT
   const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(url, {
       headers: {
           "Authorization" : process.env.GRAPH_CMS_TOKEN
       }
   })
   const pageSlug = pageContext.query.slug

   const query = gql`
   query($pageSlug: String!) {
     video(where: {
       slug: $pageSlug
     }) {
       createdAt,
       id,
       title,
       description,
       seen,
       slug,
       tags,
       thumbnail {
         url
       },
       mp4 {
         url
       }
     }
   }
   `

   const variables = {
       pageSlug,
   }

   const data = await graphQLClient.request(query, variables)
   const video = data.video

   return {
       props: {
           video
       }
   }
}

const Video = ({video}) => {
   console.log(video);
   return (
      <div></div>
   )

}

export default Video
```

when I visit "http://localhost:3000/video/jaws" I get this error.
I'm using GraphCMS as my CMS.

Comment: What value does `process.env.ENDPOINT` have? Is it a relative or absolute URL?

Comment: @juliomalves "https://api-eu-central-1.graphcms.com/v2/cktrcml932edq01yzas474yxj/master".
I got it from graphCMS. That's how i connected my app to the backend